# Django Project: django-admin.py: command not found

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, web

I'm trying to create a Django project. I've looked up solutions everywhere and it is still not working.

I am running Python 2.7 and Django 1.3.1.

I have tried to create a symbolic link but it doesn't work because django-admin.py already exists.

Here is the bash:

```
user@user:~$ django-admin.py startproject mysite
django-admin.py: command not found

user@user:~$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/bin/django-adminpy /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py': File exists
```

Comment: python django-admin.py startproject mysite

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have tried that and I have gotten: user@user:~$ python django-admin.py startproject mysite
python: can't open file 'django-admin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: I know it's off topic, but did you consider using a recent version of django if you are creating a new project?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
user@user:~$ django-admin startproject mysite
```

Answer (score 2):

Check whether `/usr/local/bin` is in `$PATH`.

If it is not in `$PATH`, set it as follow.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I will keep this in mind

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you got the right directory. You can do so by changing directory (cd) as such

```
cd C:\
```

then if `django-admin startproject mysite` does not work

try this instead `./django-admin startproject mysite`

Answer (score -3):

Type `python django-admin startproject mysite` in PowerShell.